# Why the browser closes by itself (Process finished with exit code 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use PyCharm. I don't know why the browser is closing itself. Please help me.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


options = Options()

ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=options)
driver.get("my page")

driver.find_element(By.ID, "form-email").send_keys("my e-mail")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "form-password").send_keys("my password")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='Wrapper-sc-8so8sv eyQKCA']").submit()
```

Comment: Is it closing after `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='Wrapper-sc-8so8sv eyQKCA']").submit()` ?

Comment: I don't know how to check it?

Comment: What happens when you execute the script ?

Comment: It goes to my page (zalando-lounge.pl), it writes my e-mail and password in correct fields, it submits "Dalej" (go further) and browser closes itself

Comment: without fake_useragent it logs in but it gives an error on the page so I guessed that site is blocking my python script and I need to change user-agent.

Comment: Is your concern about the _browser_ closing or the _Python interpreter_ closing? Because I don't see your code doing anything that would obviously keep it open, and if the Python interpreter exiting also causes the browser it started to be shut down in the process, well, there you are.

Comment: My concern is about browser closing. Without fake_useragent it keeps open. My code does nothing to close it, too. I don't know why it closes itself as I mentioned above.

Comment: Now I found a line `options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)` to keep my browser tab open, but I don't know what else is blocking my python script that I can't log-in.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your last line is a button.

> 'driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='Wrapper-sc-8so8sv
> eyQKCA']").submit()'

You should try the .click() method instead of .submit()